# JSF: p:commandLinks not working when selectionMode is multiple in datatable

Tags: jsf

I am working on a xhtml file that has inputtexts, commandlinks and data table. Part of the content of the file would be something like this:

```
<div>
      <h:inputText value="#{MyBean.inputval}" />
      <p:commandLink value="Button A" action="#{MyBean.actionA}" />
      <p:commandLink value="Button B" action="#{MyBean.actionB}" />
</div>
<p:dataTable value="#{MyBean.dataList}" var="data">
      <p:columnGroup type="header">
         <p:row>
           <p:column headerText="headerA" selectionMode="multiple" rowspan="2" />
           <p:column headerText="headerB" />
         </p:row>
         <p:row>
           <p:column headerText="headerB2" />
         </p:row>
      </p:columnGroup>

      // This column is the source of the problem
      <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />

      <p:column><h:outputText value="#{data.get('hb')}" /><br/>
                <h:outputText value="#{data.get('hb2')}" />
      </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The above works fine if I remove the selectionMode="multiple" on the part of the dataTable, I have pointed out via a comment. The issue is none of my commandlinks work. I get no errors whatsoever, nothing just happens.

However, if I removed the selectionMode="multiple", all of my commandlinks work but the checkbox on the table header that will select all checkboxes is disabled.

My question is how can I make both work? What am I doing wrong? Please help

Comment: Why you have declared two columns with selectionMode="multiple". I believe its not correct. And if you declared <p:column selectionMode="multiple" /> then you should declare selection attribute of data table which should be mapped to a variable array or list of object in your managed bean.

Comment: I added two columns with selectionMode="multiple" because after populating the dataTable, the checkboxes that are supposed to appear on the column corresponding to the selectionmode does not appear. Thank you for the suggestion, I am trying it out. I'm new to using jsf and java so this is very confusing.

Comment: See this link to get an idea how to use multiple selection using checkbox. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf

Answer (score 0):

Your `p:column` in the header cant have a `headerText` because this is a special primefaces function. You want to check the header checkbox for all subrows be selected. just adpot the same style as used in the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml).